# What are the benefits and drawbacks of timed online exams?

Tags: teaching, exams, education, online-learning, covid-19

I have seen several ideas for online exams but one thing that is not fully discussed is what are the advantages and disadvantages of timed exams? This will be helpful to many, especially during these times.

Comment: How is this not just opinion based?

Comment: You've identified some of the pros and cons of time-limited exams.  Weighing those pros and cons is a judgement call that each instructor should answer for themselves.

Comment: The answer is going to be highly dependent on one's discipline and one's pedagogical approach. In English, I would ask essay questions and evaluate them to a higher standard, since students will have sufficient time to find and use sources and quotes. A quantitative field would likely work differently.

Comment: @Buffy proving students with more time on online exams could increase the level of cheating. Do you think it is an opinion?

Comment: @BrianBorchers can we have a post that lists all these pros and cons so instructors can make a better decision?

Comment: @ThomasLee you can edit your question to do that if you'd like.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Ok, done

Comment: @JonCuster many are doing 1/2 day or more

Comment: @JonCuster: I am pretty sure that a time limit in the question refers to, say 1-5 hours and not to "until the instructor dies" or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, there must be some time limit, since the results must be submitted to be graded before the end of the course. For many courses in the humanities, the 'exam' is instead a paper to be worked on over a period of time (perhaps a week) and turned in by a given time. I suspect this is not what you are looking for.

Instead, you are asking about an on-line exam given to the full class (or group) of students, where they accomplish the exercise in one sitting of some length. So, what should that length be? Traditional in-class exams are limited by the length of the class period, since some students may have a class directly afterwards. The final exam schedules that I have experienced also allot a fixed time interval, usually several hours. Again, different students with different class schedules may have other exams to get to. At the institutions I attended there were also appeal processes if a student had too many exams scheduled in a given time. For instance, each day in finals week had 3 exam slots, and you did not have to take 3 in a given day - they would move one for you. But each slot was a fixed length to make sure there was time to decompress, eat, do a quick review, and then get to the next exam. It was strictly forbidden for an instructor to go beyond the fixed time.

So, while you may feel that you want to give your students lots of time (just why I don't know - fit the material to a fixed time that one can reasonably expect students to work straight through), they have other demands on their time. By being 'nice' to your students you are in essence being greedy by taking away their time to meet other classes' obligations. Discuss with your registrar. Even in these unusual times, don't be a burden on your students.